# Added to layout page scripts dont work in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

While making my ASP.NET project I've faced a problem that script's, which were wrote in "Head" section in my layout page, are not available to use in rendered view.
Content of layout page looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inner page contains Bootstrap's Carousel, which is not working if I havent put the "script" strings directly into inner page.
What am I missing? Why cant i add scripts into layout?

Comment: `jquery.js` need to be before `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Also you aren't using paths properly. Try `src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"` or simply `src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"` for both javascript and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of fact, that layout and body are merging into single page, ASP.NET still recognises that layout file is one node deeper in file system and generate pathes accordingly.So the GSerg was right: [Added to layout page scripts dont work in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059534/added-to-layout-page-scripts-dont-work-in-asp-net-mvc-5?noredirect=1#comment46355636_29059534)

Answer (score -1):

Not true.  They just must be loaded at the bottom of the page just above the closing "body" tag in most cases.  The divs, ids, etc that you are trying to manipulate will not have been generated at the time those js scripts run.

If you're using MVC 5, bundling is a much easier way to handle both your CSS and js, IMHO.

Comment: This answer is misleading. While it might be advised for *performance* reasons to include script blocks at the bottom of the page, one still has to make sure the scripts execute only [when DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), which ensures *correctnes* regardless of whether the script is included from `<head>` or from the bottom of the page. Bundling, in turn, is a completely separate concept that does not really affect the above issue.

Comment: Not at all.  Jquery allows very simply for DOM ready calls.  Although, I will concede that bundling is a separate issue, which is why it was in a distinct paragraph duly noted as an opinion.